# Is there a 'clamp' method/sub for ranges/Num etc in Raku (i.e. Perl6)?

Tags: raku, clamp

Is there a 'clamp' or equivalent method or sub in Perl6?

eg

```perl
my $range= (1.0 .. 9.9)
my $val=15.3;

my $clamped=$range.clamp($val);
# $clamped would be 9.9

$val= -1.3;
$clamped=$range.clamp($val);
# $clamped would be 1.0
```

Comment: Ha ha the line noise version: `my ($i,$l,$ll)=(50,1,10); say $i>$l??$l!!$i <$ll??$ll!!$i;`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Another tact you might like to explore is using a [Proxy](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Proxy), which allows you to define "hooks" when fetching or storing a value from a container

```
sub limited-num(Range $range) is rw {
    my ($min, $max) = $range.minmax;
    my Numeric $store = $min;
    Proxy.new(
        FETCH => method () { $store },
        STORE => method ($new) {
            $store = max($min, min($max, $new));
        }
    )
}

# Note the use of binding operator `:=`
my $ln := limited-num(1.0 .. 9.9);
say $ln;     # OUTPUT: 1

$ln += 4.2;  
say $ln;     # OUTPUT: 5.2

$ln += 100;  
say $ln;     # OUTPUT: 9.9

$ln -= 50;   
say $ln;     # OUTPUT: 1

$ln = 0;     
say $ln;     # OUTPUT: 1
```

This particular `limited-num` will initialise with it's min value, but you can also set it at declaration

```
my $ln1 := limited-num(1.0 .. 9.9) = 5.5;
say $ln1;    # OUTPUT 5.5;

my $ln2 := limited-num(1.0 .. 9.9) = 1000;
say $ln2;    # OUTPUT 9.9
```

Answer (score 6):

I don't think so. So, perhaps:

```
multi clamp ($range, $value) {
  given $range {
    return .max when (($value cmp .max) === More);
    return .min when (($value cmp .min) === Less);
  }
  return $value
} 
my $range = (1.0 .. 9.9);
say $range.&clamp: 15.3; # 9.9
say $range.&clamp: -1.3; # 1

my $range = 'b'..'y';
say $range.&clamp: 'a'; # b
say $range.&clamp: 'z'; # y
```

---

The [MOP](https://docs.perl6.org/language/mop) allows direct exploration of the objects available in your P6 system. A particularly handy metamethod is `.^methods` which works on most built in objects:

```
say Range.^methods; # (new excludes-min excludes-max infinite is-int ...
```

By default this includes just the methods defined in the `Range` class, not the methods it inherits. (To get them all you could use `say Range.^methods: :all`. That'll net you a much bigger list.)

When I just tried it I found it also included a lot of methods unhelpfully named `Method+{is-nodal}.new`. So maybe use this instead:

```
say Range.^methods.grep: * !~~ / 'is-nodal' /;
```

This netted:

```
(new excludes-min excludes-max infinite is-int elems iterator
flat reverse first bounds int-bounds fmt ASSIGN-POS roll pick
Capture push append unshift prepend shift pop sum rand in-range
hyper lazy-if lazy item race of is-lazy WHICH Str ACCEPTS perl
Numeric min max BUILDALL)
```

That's what I used to lead me to my solution above; I sort of know the methods but use `.^methods` to remind me.

---

Another way to explore what's available is doc, eg [the official doc's `Range` page](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Range). That netted me:

```
ACCEPTS min excludes-min max excludes-max bounds
infinite is-int int-bounds minmax elems list flat
pick roll sum reverse Capture rand
```

---

Comparing these two lists, sorted and bagged, out of curiosity:

```
say

<ACCEPTS ASSIGN-POS BUILDALL Capture Numeric Str WHICH append
 bounds elems excludes-max excludes-min first flat fmt hyper 
 in-range infinite int-bounds is-int is-lazy item iterator
 lazy lazy-if max min new of perl pick pop prepend push
 race rand reverse roll shift sum unshift>.Bag

 ∩

<ACCEPTS Capture bounds elems excludes-max excludes-min flat
 infinite int-bounds is-int list max min minmax pick
 rand reverse roll sum>.Bag
```

displays:

```
Bag(ACCEPTS, Capture, bounds, elems, excludes-max, excludes-min,
flat, infinite, int-bounds, is-int, max, min, pick,
rand, reverse, roll, sum)
```

So for some reason, `list`, `minmax`, and `sum` are documented as `Range` methods but are not listed by my `.^methods` call. Presumably they're called `Method+{is-nodal}.new`. Hmm.

```
say Range.^lookup('minmax'); # Method+{is-nodal}.new
say Range.^lookup('minmax').name; # minmax
```

Yep. Hmm. So I could have written:

```
say Range.^methods>>.name.sort;

(ACCEPTS ASSIGN-POS AT-POS BUILDALL Bag BagHash Capture EXISTS-POS
 Mix MixHash Numeric Set SetHash Str WHICH append bounds elems
 excludes-max excludes-min first flat fmt hyper in-range infinite
 int-bounds is-int is-lazy item iterator lazy lazy-if list max min
 minmax new of perl pick pop prepend push race rand reverse roll
 shift sum unshift)
```

---

Anyhow, hope that's helpful.

Comment: Thanks for that. Simple enough make a sub, I just wasn't sure if it was implemented as some perl6-ism. I haven't gone into the MOP in any depth ATM, so more to learn ;)

Comment: For my immediate purpose I went for an 'inline' : `$rate= $rate > 0.1??0.1!!$rate; $rate= $rate < -0.1??-0.1!!$rate;`

Comment: Yw. I think most folk could use P6 for years without ever needing to look into the MOP and not realizing they're using it when they write things like `say WHAT 42`. About the only thing I recall off the top of my head ever using it for beyond that (and similar like `HOW`) is `.^methods` and `.^lookup`.

Answer (score 0):

Strange that no one has suggested using `augment`.  Admittedly, it creates global changes, but that might not be an issue.

```
augment class Range {
   method clamp ($value) { ... }
}
```

You will need to use the pragma`use MONKEY-TYPING` in the same scope before the `augment` in order to use it though.  But this way, you can simply say `$range.clamp(5)`, for instance.  It saves you one character over raiph's answer, but at the (not insignificant) cost of breaking precompilation.